# Utilizar alias en operaciones matemáticas SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

¿Es posible utilizar alias para una operación matemática en SQL Oracle? Estoy intentando realizar la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT TITULO,AÑO,(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY')) - AÑO) 
"TRANSCURRIDOS" FROM PELICULA WHERE TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY')) > 
25
```

Lo que me gustaría saber es si el alias "Transcurridos" podría utilizarlo en el where, sin necesidad de repetir la sentencia matemática.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer, de forma directa, no es posible. Por qué? porque en la linea de tiempo de la ejecución de la consulta el **where** ocurre primero que el select, el motor filtra primero, extrae los datos, crea el cursor y los presenta. En este orden de ideas el alias aun no existe cuando el motor va haciendo el where. Una opcion (poco recomendable si tabla es muy grande) es:

```
    select * from (SELECT TITULO,AÑO,(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY')) - AÑO) 
    AS TRANSCURRIDOS FROM PELICULA) WHERE TRANSCURRIDOS > 
    25
```

O mantener la consulta tal como la llevas hasta ahi.

Espero te sirva!

Answer (score 0):

Actualmente no puedes utilizar alias a la hora de dentro de la cláusula `WHERE` pero podrías implementar una función que hiciera el cálculo y luego llamarla donde te interesara.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de creación de una función:

```
CREATE [OR REPLACE] FUNCTION function_name
   [ (parameter [,parameter]) ]

   RETURN return_datatype

IS | AS

   [declaration_section]

BEGIN
   executable_section

[EXCEPTION
   exception_section]

END [function_name];
```

Para utilizarla sólo tendrías que hacer:

```
SELECT customFunction(parameter1, parameter2, ...) AS foo
FROM foo
WHERE customFunction(parameter1, parameter2, ...) > 25
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.